# Netsuite dynamically set entry form based on record type

Tags: forms, types, record, netsuite

I would like to know how to pre-set the "**custom form**" when creating an item, based on the "record type", e.g. inventory item, serialised inventory item, lot numbered inventory item, etc.

I have try:

- nlapiSetFieldValue('customform''2') /record.setFieldValeu() in "**beforeLoad**" User event    ---> but does not work
- check record type and re-set "custom form" in "**page init**" Client Script---> system will load the preferred form first and then reload. But changing the "custom form" will trigger to call "page init" again. Need to break the dead loop with condition. But the performance is bad, since I need to preset many fields first and it at lease need to load 2 times of the forms.

So I would like to know whether there is a way to pre-set the form first based on different item record types??

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tested and working in my SDN account:

```js
function beforeLoad() {
    var formByType = {
        "serializedinventoryitem": "33"
    };

    var recordType = nlapiGetRecordType();
    var currentForm = nlapiGetFieldValue("customform");
    var desiredForm = formByType[recordType];

    if (desiredForm && (currentForm != desiredForm)) {
        nlapiSetRedirectURL("RECORD", nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId(), true, {"cf":desiredForm});
    }
}
```

Just fill out the `formByType` object with the keys being the record types and the values being the form each type should map to.

If you leave a specific type out of `formByType`, then no redirection is attempted and the preferred form would be used.

Be aware that you will need multiple deployments of this User Event script, one on each of the various item types you need to redirect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works well!!!  Please use "nlapiSetRedirectURL" to change the form instead of "setFieldValue ('customform','XX')". And do it in User Event's before load, not the Client Script's Page Init.